# javascript/jquery templating suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, templating

I am developing a large scale application highly dependent on javascript. Part of this will be displying information on screen. I am looking to display information on the ui and I am looking at using javascript templating to do such. I will be using the jquery framework.

Any suggestions or recommendations to javascript/jquery templating frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

It's not jQuery based, but according to [performance tests](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/259) on jsperf.com, the [doT.js](https://github.com/olado/doT) templating framework is consistently the fastest JS templating framework. It has no dependencies, so you should be able to use it alongside jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful library for jquery templating:  http://icanhazjs.com/  Plus, it's got a fun name!

Answer (score 1):

Only agree with GregL partially. The original test does not consider the time spent to eventually append the rendered html to the page.

You should also check out http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/259

This test will include appending the rendered html text to the page.

You can compare it with http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/257

The original test case. You will find out that the difference across template engines is not that significant. You do need to consider more about the usability of a template engine, unless you are going to simply render a chuck of html text without put it to the client browser.

Besides, in my opinion, a good template engine should greatly help you maintain
the templates, help you write less to do more which is also the principle of jQuery.

doT.js is really great in performance, but I don't agree that it could help you code efficiently.

I am now working on an open source project to try to build a easy-to-use template engine. It can help you manage your templates in a tree-like structure, create template reference, define your own syntax, bind data to html dom.. please give it a try

http://jspopisno1.github.com/Beard

You can also have a read another question in stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend/8129492#8129492

Comment: When using javascript on the server side the DOM manipulation cost of using innerHTML actually is not an issue.  Nevertheless I found the differences when doing innerHTML really intriguing and baffling.  Do you know how to explain the sharp performance changes between libraries when doing innerHTML as well?  I wonder how repeat rendering of the same snippet would factor in.  For example dot.js supports partials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i've used this [John Resig’s Microtemplating engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) with great success in several projects. It's very simple, maintainable, and easy to use.