# I get confuse with anonymous function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, function

In a tutorial I saw they used JSON to get information from twitter, and then paste in a Template (Handlebars). I'm really new with this concepts of JSON and fetching information from the server, but what confused me the most is that the anonymous function in $.JSON and $map was that they use a callback function and pass some parameters. I don´t understand where they come from and why they're referencing them. If anyone could give me a clue it would be great.
Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Twiiter API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tweets">
        <script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" >
        {{#each this}}
            <li>
                <img src = "{{thumb}}" alt= "{{author}}">
                <p><a href="{{url}}">{{tweet}}</a></p>
            </li>
        {{/each}}       
        </script> 
    </ul> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function(){
            var Twitter = {
                init: function(config){
                    this.url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + config.query + '&callback=?';

                    this.template = config.template;
                    this.container = config.container;
                    this.fetch();
                },

                attachTemplate : function(){
                        var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
                        this.container.append(template (this.tweets));
                },

                fetch: function(){
                    var self = this; // This REFERS TO TWITTER  OBJECT
                    $.getJSON(this.url, function (data){
                        //$.map WILL FILTER THROUGH AN ARRAY AND FOR EACH ONE OF THOES IT WILL EXECUTE A FUNCTION
                        self.tweets =  $.map(data.results, function(tweet){
                                return {
                                    author : tweet.from_user,
                                    tweet : tweet.text,
                                    thumb: tweet.profile_image_url,
                                    url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.form_user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str
                                };
                        });

                    self.attachTemplate();
                    });
                }
            };  
            Twitter.init({
                template:$('#tweets-template').html(),
                container:$('ul.tweets'),
                query: 'tutspremium'
            });
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make a good **search** before you ask these questions.

Learn more about **anonymous functions** here:

1. [Anonymous Function from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)
2. [Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)
3. [JavaScript closures vs. anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions)
4. [javascript: recursive anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883780/javascript-recursive-anonymous-function)
5. [How is data passed to anonymous functions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903904/how-is-data-passed-to-anonymous-functions-in-javascript)

And about **templating**, here.

1. [Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)
2. [When to use JavaScript template engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077016/when-to-use-javascript-template-engines)
3. [javascript/jquery templating suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129847/javascript-jquery-templating-suggestions)

A few insights on **callback functions**.

1. [How to explain callbacks in plain english? How are they different from calling one function from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)
2. [Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: I get confuse with in $.Json they pass data and in and in $map they pass tweet , I don´t know where they come from and why they need it